# get_page_templates only return templates with "home" in the filename

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

I have the following custom page template filenames:

- template-about-1.php
- template-about-2.php
- template-home-1.php
- template-home-2.php

I have this function to get_page_templates:

```
function get_page_templates_select() {
 $teh_cats = get_page_templates();
 foreach ( $teh_cats as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
     $results[] = $template_name;
   }
   return $results;
}
```

How can I modify the function to ONLY return the templates that have "home" in their filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after thinking it through..

```
if (stripos(strtolower($template_filename), 'home') !== false) {
    $results[] = $template_name;
}
```